# Is there any reason to use SaveChangesInterceptor instead of overriding OnBeforeSaveChanges and OnAfterSaveChanges?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Does using SaveChangesInterceptor gives any performance boost or is better in any way than just overriding following methods?

In my opinion SaveChangesInterceptor is better if I have multiple contexts and want them to use it.

Is there any other reason to use SaveChangesInterceptor instead of overriding OnBeforeSaveChanges and OnAfterSaveChanges?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between overriding methods and adding components in general is subject of the old [inheritance vs. composition](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-inheritance-and-vs-composition/) debate. An interesting difference in view of your question is that *composition* allows pluggable behavioral changes during runtime, while *inheritance* (or overriding base methods) is more suitable for static behavioral differences.

In terms of a `DbContext` -

- Use overrides (of `SaveChanges(Async)`) if a context will always need the modified behavior (for example, auditing, or making a read-only context by removing the base implementation altogether).
- Use interceptors if behavior is to be switched on and off at runtime. For example, temporary specialized logging for diagnostic purposes. If a context class has a constructor accepting `DbContextOptions` the interceptors can be added to the options conditionally.

You mention `OnBeforeSaveChanges` and `OnAfterSaveChanges`. I think you're referring to the various [DbContext events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/events#events-raised-by-ef-core). Subscribing to events is a *composition* pattern. They're a bit simpler to implement than interceptors but (see the link) they are sync only and so cannot perform non-blocking async I/O.